# twitter card not showing the meta data I provide it with nextjs 13

Tags: node.js, next.js, twitter-card

When I used nextjs13, in order to use lruchache, I used the app.renderToHTML function. However, after using this function, Twitter Card cannot detect the presence of meta tags

[image]

I tried using the app. getRequestHandler() function to rewrite the writer with response and save the chunk to the cache. But it was not successful
[image]